# Calculus of variations for double sum with Lagrange multiplier

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations

This cropped up in a research question I'm tackling.
I wish to solve the following optimization problem:
$$
\text{minimize}\ \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}
\quad\text{subject to}\ \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i=1\ \text{and}\ f_i \in [0,1]\ \forall i.
$$

My attempt was to apply calculus of variation, and adding the normalization constraint with a Lagrange multiplier:
$$
S_\lambda := \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j} + \lambda\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i \right)
$$
and then vary
$$
\frac{\delta S_\lambda}{\delta f_a} = \sum_{j=1}^a \sqrt{f_j} + \frac12 \frac{1}{\sqrt{f_a}} \sum_{i=a}^\infty f_i -\lambda \overset!= 0
\quad\forall a
$$
*(My first question is: can I even apply calculus of variation in this setting? And, if so, is the expression above correct? I asked a colleague to check who couldn't find any mistake, but you know how it is sometimes.)*

Under the assumption that the variation is correct, I then solved the first and last equation via
\begin{align}
    0= \frac{\delta S_\lambda}{\delta f_1} &= \sqrt{f_1} + \frac12 \frac{1}{\sqrt{f_1}}\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i}_{=1} - \lambda
&\Rightarrow\quad \lambda &= \frac{1+2f_1}{2 \sqrt{f_1}} \\
    0= \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\delta S_\lambda}{\delta f_a} &= - \lambda  + \underbrace{\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^a \sqrt{f_i}}_{=:A_\infty} + \frac12 \underbrace{\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{f_a}} \sum_{i=a}^\infty f_i}_{=:B_\infty} &\Rightarrow\quad \lambda&=A_\infty + B_\infty
\end{align}
As by the first line we have that $\lambda$ is finite, both limits must exist. The first sum converges when $f_i = o(1/i^2)$, in which case $B_\infty=0$ and $\lambda = A_\infty$.

*But how to proceed? I don't see a good way of e.g. solving this set of equations recursively.*

I'd be grateful for any pointers!

Comment: I got something different $0
=\frac{\delta S_\lambda}{\delta f_i}
=\frac{\delta}{\delta f_i}(\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j} + \lambda\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i \right))
=\frac{\delta}{\delta f_i}(\sum_{i=1}^\infty [f_i \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}-\lambda f_i] + \lambda)
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\delta}{\delta f_i}[f_i \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}-\lambda f_i]
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1\cdot\sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}+f_i\frac{\delta}{\delta f_i}[ \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}]-\lambda]$

Comment: $=\sum_{i=1}^\infty [\sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}+f_i\frac{\delta}{\delta f_i}[ \sqrt{f_i}+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \sqrt{f_j}]-\lambda]
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty [\sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{f_i}-\lambda]\Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}+\frac{\sqrt{f_i}}{2}-\lambda=0
\Leftrightarrow f_i=[\frac{2}{3}(\lambda-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sqrt{f_i})]^2
$

Comment: I think you might be using the same index for the sum and the derivative (i.e., try calculating $\delta S_\lambda / \delta f_a$ to have a distinct index from the sum's running index.)

Comment: The continous analog
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \int_0^x \sqrt{f(y)} \,dy \, dx
$$
has Dirac sequences at $0$ as minimizing sequences with value $0$. Regarding the discrete system as a regularization of the continuum one, one might think that $f_1=1$ is a candidate, giving value $1$ for the functional.
One can do slightly better by setting $f_i = \gamma^{i-1} (1-\gamma)$ for $\gamma\in (0,1)$, which leads to the value 
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$
The minimizer of this function gives $\gamma=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ with value approximately $0.978593$ as benchmark result.

Comment: As I see it for the continuum case  $S=\int_{x_i}^{x_f} L(x, f(x), f '(x))dx+C$ we write $\frac{\partial S}{\partial f(x)}$ instead of $\frac{\partial S}{\partial f(y)}$  so for $S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j} + \lambda(1-\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty [f_i \sum_{j=1}^i \sqrt{f_j}-\lambda f_i] + \lambda=\sum_{i=1}^\infty L(f_i) + \lambda$ one shouldn't take the functional derivative $\frac{\partial S}{\partial f(a)}$ but rather $\frac{\partial S}{\partial f(i)}$ at least I believe but we would be better if we could just put this on wolframalpha to know exactly

Comment: For example for the functional of the [Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell–Boltzmann_statistics) $f(N_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n[N_i\ln g_i-N_i\ln N_i + N_i-(\alpha+\beta\varepsilon_i) N_i]+ \alpha N +\beta E$ the variational derivative is $\frac{\delta f}{\delta N_i}=\sum_i\ln g_i-\ln N_i -(\alpha+\beta\varepsilon_i)=0\Rightarrow\frac{\partial f}{\partial N_i}=\ln g_i-\ln N_i -(\alpha+\beta\varepsilon_i) = 0$, first we do the derivate and then we select which index we want

Comment: @DanielD., I think your last comment is basically just that, $\delta f/\delta N_a$ to not clash with the sum's index; then rename $a$ to $i$ (so I think that your expression $\delta f/\delta N_i$ is actually incorrect). But maybe I'm wrong. I just treat the variation as a problem with an infinite number of independent variables.

Comment: @AndréSchlichting, this might be it. Let me check.

Comment: Great, indeed. I think that André's solution works! How did you come up with that ansatz for the $f_i$?

Comment: No, maybe I'm wrong, I just think there is no clash problem because $x$ doesn't matter in $S=\frac{\partial S}{\partial f(x)}$ with $\int_{x_i}^{x_f} L(x, f(x), f '(x))dx$ as shouldn't $i$ matter in $\frac{\partial S}{\partial f_i}$ with $S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty L(f_i) + \lambda$ so would say the notation $\delta f/\delta N_i$ is correct for the same reason but since the right way to solve it was as André Schlichting did I don't think there is a need to solve it in the original setting anymore.

Comment: Cool yeah. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: I did. Actually, I did not expect that the ansatz satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation. I was quite surprised that one can do slightly better then just having all mass concentrated at $i=1$. It could by interesting to study the problem with the square-root replace by $f_i^\alpha$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$, where the same strategy should give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic heuristic starts with looking at the continous analog
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x) \int_0^x \sqrt{f(y)} \,dy \, dx ,
$$
which has Dirac sequences at 0 as minimizing sequences with value 0. Regarding the discrete system as a regularization of the continuum one, one might think that $f_1=1$ and $f_i=0$ for $i\geq 2$ is a candidate, giving value $1$ for the functional.

However, the form of the Euler-Lagrange equation shows that one might gain something by distributing the mass around. Hence, a possible ansatz is $f_i =\gamma^{i-1}(1−\gamma)$ for $\gamma\in [0,1)$, containing the case of all mass concentrated in $i=1$ as $\gamma=0$. This ansatz leads to a value of the functional of
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
$$
The minimizer of this function in $\gamma\in [0,1)$ is given by $\gamma=\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ with value for the functional of
$$
 \sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+\frac{8}{9 \sqrt{3}}} = 0.978593 .
$$
It is left to verify that this sequence $f_i$ actually satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation, which I checked via mathematica.